# Faster way to rbind data frames from a list of lists

Tags: r, performance, lapply, rbind, do.call

I have a foreach loop that returns a list of lists. Each sub-list is a list of 3 data frames and I want to rbind them into 3 different data frames. Right now I am doing it like this:

```
x_final=data.frame
y_final=data.frame()
z_final=data.frame()
for(i in 1:length(big_list))
{
   x=big_list[[i]][1]
   y=big_list[[i]][2]
   z=big_list[[i]][3]
   x_final=rbind(x_final,x)
   y_final=rbind(y_final,y)
   z_final=rbind(z_final,z)
}
```

The problem is when length of big_list is large this loop takes a lot of time. Is there any other way of doing it faster? Any sort of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `data.table::rbindlist(list(x_final,y_final,z_final))`

Comment: There is also an `rlist` package that may be helpful: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rlist/versions/0.4.6.1  See the `list.rbind` function: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rlist/versions/0.4.6.1/topics/list.rbind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to `transpose` the `big_list` and use `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
out_lst <- transpose(big_list) %>% 
                map(bind_rows)
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work. Can you please provide an example? Also FYI, when I do class(big_list[[1]][1]) it reutrns "list" but when I do class(big_list[[1]][[1]]) it returns "data.frame". Could it be the reason why it doesn't work? Thanks

Comment: @ParasKarandikar Can you please update your post with a small reproducible example so that I can test it. thanks

Comment: I tried it with some toy data, your method works absolutely fine. However when I do it on the big_list I get an error saying "Item 1 of list input is not an atomic vector".

Comment: @ParasKarandikar It may because some of your list elements may be empty in that big list.  Can you check those

Comment: Thanks a lot! There was some conflict with transpose function of library data.table. After doing ** purrr::transpose(big_list) %>% map(bind_rows) **  works fine.

Comment: @ParasKarandikar there are multiple packages having the same function name.  Glad you spotted that

Comment: I have some empty data frames in sub-lists but that does not cause any issues. Thanks again.